# Play Billing Library and Adobe Creative SDK : IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class duplicated entry Exception

Tags: android, in-app-billing, adobecreativesdk

Adobe Creative SDK include a IInAppBillingService.

Google released the Play Billing Library `com.android.billingclient:billing` and it include a IInAppBillingService also.
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html

When you use the Play Billing Library and Creative SDK at the same time. you may run into the following build error.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class

Is there any solution? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Creative SDK include a IInAppBillingService, its version is In-app Billing (IAB Version 3).
So you can NOT use Play Billing Library 1.0.

If you want to use Adobe Creative SDK, please use In-app Billing (IAB Version 3).